# VS CODE LOST AFTER RESTART IN PARROT LINUX

Tags: visual-studio-2015, parrot-os

I am using Parrot Security MATE ISO Linux and have downloaded VS code. But everytime I shutdown my PC the installation is lost and have to reinstall again.

Answer (score 0):

I was also experiencing this.

I solved this by downloading the debian package from 'https://code.visualstudio.com/download'
and running `sudo dpkg -i ~/Downloads/code_*.deb` from terminal. I've restarted several times since and all is well thus far.

Initially I was just downloading and running the 'package installer' GUI which seemed to cause this issue of vanishing after reboot.